# BSD or MIT licensed Windows DLL Assembler & Linker

Tags: windows, assembly, linker

I need an Open Source assembler with a linker that is capable of producing Windows 32 bit and **64 bit** DLLs. And is **not** GPL, but is open source with a BSD or MIT or some similar license. Does this exist?

**Update**: GNU Binutils is perfect (as and ld). But the GNU GPL license is unacceptable.

Comment: Just curious, what makes GPL unacceptable?

Comment: @djdanlib proprietary software.

Comment: In what context?  It is perfectly legal (though perhaps frowned upon) to compile proprietary code with GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a bit vague on what your exact requirements are...
... but perhaps OpenWatcom might be the ticket for you.

It does DOS, DPMI, Win16 and Win32; it has an assembler, compiler and linker; and it's "Open Source".  Here's the specific license:

- http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Open_Watcom_Public_License

I'd strongly encourage you to look at Gnu and Dgjpp, too.  Depending on your exact requirements, either/both *might* be acceptable to you:

- http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq19_2.html
- http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html

Comment: If sb asks for BSD license, GPL is usually not allowed :-)

Answer (score 0):

- [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) is licensed under BSD-2
- [YASM](http://yasm.tortall.net/) (a NASM rewrite) is licensed under BSD-3, unlike NASM additionally has AT&T syntax support
- [JWasm](http://www.japheth.de/JWasm.html) (an OpenWatcom fork) has a custom license, in any case less strict than GPL, MASM style syntax

They all produce 32-bit and 64-bit Windows binaries.

EDIT: Just realized NASM and YASM don't come with a linker, but JWAsm has the accompanying [JWlink](http://www.japheth.de/JWlink.html).

Comment: I disagree that JWasm's license is any less strict than the GPL.